# trying to put an mysql result into a string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to put an mysql query result into an string
I tried to find an answer but all the similar posts were getting subquery answers which is not what I'm trying to do.

for example

```
    +----------------------------------+
    |            Fruits_tbl            |
    +----+---------+---------+---------+
    | ID |  Fruit  |  Color  |  Number |
    +----+---------+---------+---------+
    |  1 |  Orange |  Orange |    3    |
    |  2 |  Apple  |  Red    |    5    |
    +----+---------+---------+---------+



    $sql = "select Fruits,Color,Number from Fruits_tbl where ID = 2";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch();
    print_r($row);
```

This will give me something like 
Array([0]=>"Apple", [1]=>"Red", [2]=>"5", [Fruit]=>"Apple", [Color]=>"Red", [Number]=>"5")

implode will give me 2 of each
I want just need a string = "Apple, Red, 5"

what I currently have is

```
$string = $row['Fruit'].", ".$row['Color'].", ".$row['Number']
```

As you can see that's rather tedious. 
Is there something like implode but only return the index array or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to get just an associative array:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or, you can get a list:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Either of those could be imploded for single values, and would not contain the overhead that an array_unique() would.

Comment: ah, never knew you could fetch like that. Should I be doing fetch like this with normal queries too? like a select * from a multi row table?

Answer (score 1):

`$row[Fruit].", ".$row[Color]` needs to be `$row['Fruit'].", ".$row['Color']`

I misunderstood what you were trying to do.

use `array_unique()` and implode them.

```
$string = rtrim(implode(',', array_unique($your_array)),',');
```

Comment: sorry I typed that off my head and left out the quotes

Comment: @user1583432 This is somewhat inefficient, as it requires storing twice the data, then uniquing it using array_unique.  Modify your fetch, and you don't need to use a second function.  In other word it works, but it's pretty hackish, and the code is a bit difficult to read.  Order could be a little iffy here too.